# Alternative to deep if-else trees?

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns, industrial

I have recently had the pleasure to observe a code that is essentially kilometers of very deep if-else statements. The code is continuously being updated, and keeping track of the possible outcomes and their interactions is becoming progressively harder. It feels like one can do better.

I have had an idea of maybe separating the if-tree into one file, and outcomes into another. Perhaps one could even construct a matrix, where every row would be an outcome, and every possible question one might ask would be a column. Then one could do some basic logical operations on such a matrix to automatically determine if a newly added branch interferes with already existing ones.

I'm aware this idea is very vague, but I am sure somebody must have thought about optimizing if-else trees in terms of human design and edit time.

Are there any industry standards for dealing with deep if-else trees in an efficient way? If yes, I would appreciate names and links

In this particular case, I am talking about C#, but I am also interested how the problem is addressed in general

Comment: Your second paragraph neatly describes a *decision table*, which is a standard technique for analysing, and implementing, the type of twisted logic you describe.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks, it seems like the right direction. I'll google for it

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Take a look at Drools or JRules or any other rule engine which will have decision tables inbuilt (instead of reinventing the wheel)